# Google Maps API Key - URL Restrictions

Tags: javascript, google-maps

A few days ago i generated an API Key to embed Google Maps in my projects. It works pretty well, because i made no restrictions - so basically everyone could have used the key.

Today i tried to make some restrictions, based on my domain - but i have a couple of problems:

**Absolute URLs with URI works pretty fine - e.g**.

```
http://example.com/myFirstTest.html
```

or

```
http://example.com/mySecondTest.html
```

*Google allows schema restriction like:*

```
*example.com/*
```

which i have tried without any success, because the Maps API responds with "[RefererNotAllowedMapError](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?hl=en)" which references to my only restriction i made?

**I also tried another absolute URL without any URI / Parameter:**

```
example.com/*
```

and

```
example.com/
```

again - without any success.

**A wildcard pattern isn't working either:**

```
example.com/*.html
```

or

```
*example.com/*.html
```

Please let me know, if you need more informations!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you mentioned trying

```
*example.com/*
```

Have you tried something like this instead?

```
*.example.com/*
```

I used an API key of my own and JSBin to test this out. If I just authorize:

```
jsbin.com/*
```

I get an error, but it works fine if I authorize:

```
*.jsbin.com/*
```

I'd recommend trying to authorize like my example directly above, making sure you have a wildcard for any subdomains or subpaths.

I hope this helps!